# Special comment snippet for VIM

Tags: vim

I want to add comments dependant on the column i'm writing for example if i'm adding a comment over a code which is indented 4 spaces the comment should look like

```
/* Comment -------------*/
```

as many dashes as needed to fill up the line till column 100. It should recognize where the position is and how long the comment is.

I can't figure it out with vimscript myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this with an *expression mapping*; see `:help :map-expr`:

```
:inoreabbrev <expr> comsep '/* Comment ' . repeat('-', 17 - indent('.')) . '*/'
```

This determines the width by subtracting the current indent (via `indent()`) from a constant. You could use `&textwidth` here, too.

Whenever you type `comsep`, it'll be expanded. Alternatively, you could also use an `:inoremap <expr> <C-g> ...` instead.

To insert the comment text, you could either use `input()`, or first just insert dashes and re-position the cursor by appending a number of `"\<Left>` keycodes.

If you use a *snippet plugin* like snipMate or Ultisnips, those may have functionality to dynamically modify the snippet, but the built-in methods should suffice.

Comment: ill have a try. in the documentation of snipmate i didn't find something similar to my problem (like repeating n times)

Comment: Original snipMate cannot do this dynamically as you type the comment (Ultisnips might). You can use Vimscript expressions in backticks, but these are only evaluated once when expanding the snippet.

Comment: the command you posted actually doesnt work. it puts just the code into the line after hitting enter.

Comment: You need the `<expr>`; it'll expand after space or enter.

Comment: yes i meant i actually type "comsep" press enter and then it inserts this: '/* Comment ' . repeat('-', 17 - indent('.')) . '*/'

Comment: That should work. Do you have an old Vim version? Also, try with `vim -N -u NONE`.

Comment: I run GVIM 7.4 on windows -- edit: wow on my linux machine this works totally.